# Steam crashes immediately on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: steam

When I try to launch Steam, either by running `steam` in a terminal or by using a shortcut icon, I get a dialog box that says Steam is updating and then it exits.

See [this YouTube video](https://youtu.be/oS2czc8LYQ0) which shows the problem.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add more details. What Ubuntu are you running? How did you launch steam? Describe what is in your video with words _here_ (don't expect people to go and watch some video just to understand your question; the video can be supporting information, but we need some detail here too).

Comment: pls also copy the output of the terminal (when you run steam) into your question, also  pls provide some info how you installled steam, did you use any tutorial/howto or just installed it from the package-manger?

Comment: Thank you for posting your solution! Could you please post it as an answer instead so the question can be marked as answered?

Answer (score 1):

You added this to your question:

> It's fixed now by running
>
> ```
> sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386
> sudo apt install lib32z1 lib32ncurses6
> ```

Comment: Please flag/delete this answer if Dzaky74 posts their own!